# SSLPassPhraseDialog problems - doesn't appear to be working

Tags: apache, ssl, mod-ssl

I have two certificates (one RSA and one ECDSA) for my website. I have configured a VHost to handle the SSL work, and configured an SSLPassPhraseDialog to echo out the appropriate password to Apache on startup (I know this is insecure, but its no worse than removing the passphrase entirely). With this configuration, I get the following message:

```
Apr 24 11:05:01 appsrv.lan apachectl[223544]: AH00513: WARNING: MaxRequestWorkers of 400 is not an integer multiple of ThreadsPerChild of 32, decreasing to nearest multiple 384, for a maximum of 12 servers.
Apr 24 11:05:01 appsrv.lan apachectl[223544]: Apache/2.4.56 mod_ssl (Pass Phrase Dialog)
Apr 24 11:05:01 appsrv.lan apachectl[223544]: Some of your private key files are encrypted for security reasons.
Apr 24 11:05:01 appsrv.lan apachectl[223544]: In order to read them you have to provide the pass phrases.
Apr 24 11:05:01 appsrv.lan apachectl[223544]: Private key esolutions.caspersbox.com:10943:0 (/opt/Apache/httpd/current/ssl.d/keys/esolutions.caspersbox.com-ecc.key)
Apr 24 11:05:01 appsrv.lan apachectl[223544]: Enter pass phrase:Apache:mod_ssl:Error: Private key not found.
```

I'm not sure whats wrong. If I remove the dialog option and just start the server things are fine.